# iostream not writing to binary file despite correct flag

Tags: c++, serialization, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am trying to write a string to a binary file, to that effect I made this snippet:

```
  std::string outname = filename.substr(0, filename.size() - 4) + std::string("_bin") + std::string(".sdf");
  std::cout << "Writing results to: " << outname << "\n";

  std::ofstream outfile(outname.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary);

  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << phi_grid.ni << " " << phi_grid.nj << " " << phi_grid.nk << std::endl;
  ss << min_box[0] << " " << min_box[1] << " " << min_box[2] << std::endl;
  ss << dx << std::endl;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < phi_grid.a.size(); ++i)
  {
    ss << phi_grid.a[i] << std::endl;
  }
  outfile.write(ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().size());
  outfile.close();
```

This however always writes to a text file, not a binary file. I don't udnerstand why, the flag is explicitely passed to the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "writes to a text file"? C++ strings use ASCII usually which is the same in text and binary format since both are just bytes.

Comment: A stringstream contains text. In a binary file text looks like text too. Normally you'd do something like `outfile.write(&phi_grid.ni, sizeof(phi_grid.ni));` and repeat that for all of your different variables.

Comment: The **only** difference of stream opened with `binary` flag is treatment of `\n` on systems which treat the differently for text files (i.e. Windows). In your example you are writing text string to your stream, and you should expect the same string in the file.

Comment: @Quimby I am an idiot I understand what you mean adn what my error is.

Comment: @SergeyA that's not the only difference, the eof character for example causes trouble on a Windows text file

Comment: On a side note, don't call `ss.str()` twice in your `write()` call. Save the value to a local variable first, and then use that instead, eg: `string s = ss.str(); outfile.write(s.c_str(), s.size());`

Comment: @AlanBirtles good catch. There could be a couple of more, I agree.